# How to group elements based on same specific css attribute using java script or jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am working on a page that returns in which i am having many tags that have same css attribute values, i want to see how many types of different values of specific css attribute i am having.

```
<p style="position:absolute;left:387.5px;top:204px">1</p>
<p style="position:absolute;left:47.5px;top:204px">2</p>
```

&

```
<p style="position:absolute;left:387.5px;top:500px">1</p>
<p style="position:absolute;left:47.5px;top:500px">1</p>
```

i want that i should get two types of values 204 and 500 as result of same css property 'top' !

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: i want to group html tags based on a specific css attribute

Comment: like in above case 4 <p> tags are having two different values for css property 'top' (first two --> 204px  and other two --> 500px)

Comment: How should grouping occur? Should elements having same `css` `top` value be 1) placed in a new container element;  or 2) only be grouped as siblings?

Comment: Having same/different top values but different left values when they are in same container

Comment: like in my above quoted example code, first two are in one container and below two are supposed to be in some other container.

Comment: _"Having same/different top values but different left values when they are in same container"_ ? How should elements by grouped together? The elements at Question are already grouped together, where they have same value at `css` `top`

Comment: you are right, but how we are going to see how many different values are there for top property, if the two or more elements are having different top values in same container

Comment: I think what @guest271314 is asking is, what is the structure of the return value you expect? Are you looking for an array of the existing 'top' values, or a collection of DOM elements for each value, or do you just need the equivalent of a sorted `grep "top:"` against your html file, or what?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `$.map()`, `$.unique()`, `.filter()`, `.css()`

```js
$(function() {

  $.map(
    // filter unique `css` `top` values, remove duplicates
    $.unique(
      // return `css` `top` values
      $.map($("p"), function(el) {
        return $(el).css("top")
      })
    ), function(val, key) {
      // create new container for grouping elements 
      // having same `css` `top` value
      $("<div>", {
          // filter `p` elements having same `css` `top` value
          html: $("p").filter(function() {
            return $(this).css("top") === val
          })
        })
        // append container `div` to `body`
        .appendTo("body")
    })

})
```

```css
}
) div {
  border: 1px solid blue;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js">
</script>
<p style="position:absolute;left:387.5px;top:204px">1</p>
<p style="position:absolute;left:387.5px;top:500px">1</p>
<p style="position:absolute;left:47.5px;top:204px">2</p>
<p style="position:absolute;left:47.5px;top:500px">1</p>
```

Comment: i really appreciate your effort, can we store these unique values in array, can you please show me how to do it ?

Comment: Not certain if interpreted Question correctly; was creating stacksnippets when comment at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37079050/how-to-group-elements-based-on-same-specific-css-attribute-using-java-script-or/37079581#comment61703636_37079050 was posted. Do you only want to count how many items within an existing container have a specific `css` property and value?

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve what you want doing something like this:

```
    var jqObj = $('p');
    var grupObj = {};

    groupBy('top');

    function groupBy(attr) {
        /// creating an object that will containt all the elements, this object will group the elements with the same attribute value in an array
        jqObj.each(function (idx, el) {
            var atrVal = el.style[attr];
            if (!grupObj[atrVal]) {
                grupObj[atrVal] = [];

            }
            grupObj[atrVal].push(el);
        });

        //going trough all the 'groups'
        for (var group in grupObj) {
            var grpArray = grupObj[group];
            var grpDiv = $('<div><div>');

            //appending each element to one container
            for (var i = 0; i < grpArray.length; i++) {
                grpDiv.append(grpArray[i]);
            }
            //adding the div container to the body
            $('body').append(grpDiv);
        }
    }
```